# Куда расходуется память в веб-приложении на Java?

Tags: java, память

На сервере запустил веб-приложение на Java и Tomcat с подключением к MySQL. Для ограничения памяти задал следующие опции:

```
-d64 -server -Xss128k -Xms16M -Xmx32M -XX:PermSize=32M -XX:MaxPermSize=48M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=16M -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Согласно моим ожиданиям, приложении должно занимать в памяти 104Мб (с учётом 64 потоков, реально меньше).

Но после запуска java-процесс занимает примерно 200Мб (судя по полю RES утилиты top). Через несколько часов ничего неделания, приложение уже занимает больше 300Мб.

На что расходуются эти 200Мб памяти и можно ли их как-то ограничить средствами Java?

На странице статистики Tomcat'а статистика по памяти есть, но там отражаются только те области памяти, про которые я и так знаю и которые уже успешно ограничены. В [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117274) на диаграмме есть область памяти Misc, которая занимает достаточно много места, но в самой статье не сказано, что, же входит в эту область памяти. Сам найти не смог, поэтому прошу помощи здесь.

**Обновление**

Снял дамп, после нескольких минут активной работы с приложением. При снятии дампа процесс java занимал 300Мб памяти, согласно статистике Tomcat'а использовано было всего 64Мб (Heap + PermGen + CodeCache). Открыл дамп в jVisualVM и там указано "Total bytes: 31 966 394". Подозреваю, что анализом одного лишь heap не обойтись.

Что интересно под виндой в диспетчере задач java-процесса занимает мало памяти - порядка 64Мб, как и положено. Может всё-таки дело не в утечках, а в какой-то области памяти типа кеша, про которую я ещё не знаю.

Comment: Вопрос сколько памяти *на самом деле* занимет программа вообще крайне не однозначен. Достаточно сказать, что в эти "RES" попадут  страницы всех  системных .so, к которым обращалась программа. Поскольку это общий ресурс (делится на всех в системе), то можно было бы и не учитывать его, только вот "отделить мух от котлет" задешево в \*nix не получается.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Но если это системные библиотеки, значит есть способ посмотреть, какие из них вызываются процессом, и определить виновника такого большого потребления памяти. Вы не знаете случайно такой способ?

Comment: Почитайте в [man proc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) разделы о /proc/[pid]/maps, /proc/[pid]/statm,  /proc/[pid]/status и анализируйте поведение своего процесса / (а вообще, чего еще можно ожидать от Java :)?) / Сразу хочу сказать,  что в реальности такой анализ -- дело неблагодарное, поскольку (если в системе в целом нет проблем с памятью) Вас может волновать лишь активный набор страниц да cache miss rate (а вот как стандартными средствами вытащить статистику по ним, я не знаю)

Answer (score 3):

На тостере подсказали похожий вопрос с ответом: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145769/limit-jvm-process-memory-on-ubuntu/9146775#9146775

Ниже перевод:

---

Вы не можете контролировать то, что хотите контролировать.  -Xmx влияет только на Java Heap и не влияет на потребление памяти JVM нативными средствами, которое зависит от реализации JVM.

Из статьи [Thanks for the Memory ( Understanding How the JVM uses Native Memory on Windows and Linux )](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/):

- ***Обслуживание динамической памяти Java и сборщика мусора*** требует использования нативной памяти, на которое вы не можете повлиять.

  > More native memory is required to maintain the state of the memory-management system maintaining the Java heap. Data structures must be allocated to track free storage and record progress when collecting garbage. The exact size and nature of these data structures varies with implementation, but many are proportional to the size of the heap.
  >
  > Дополнительная нативная память требуется для поддерживания работы системы управления памятью Java. Необходимо где-то хранить структуры данных, отслеживающие доступную память и следящие за состоянием уборки мусора. Точный размер и природа этих структур данных зависит от конкретной реализации, но зачастую пропорционально зависит от размера выделяемой динамической памяти.
- ***JIT-компилятор*** использует нативную память, как это делал бы компилятор Java.

  > Bytecode compilation uses native memory (in the same way that a static compiler such as gcc requires memory to run), but both the input (the bytecode) and the output (the executable code) from the JIT must also be stored in native memory. Java applications that contain many JIT-compiled methods use more native memory than smaller applications.
  >
  > При компиляции байт-кода используется нативная память (точно так же, как статический компилятор, например gсc, использует память в процессе работы), да и как входные (байт-код) так и выходные данные (машинный код) JIT-компилятора приходится хранить в нативной памяти. То есть Java-приложения, содержащие много компилируемых JIT-ом методов требуют больше нативной памяти.
- **Загрузчики классов** используют нативную память.

  > Java applications are composed of classes that define object structure and method logic. They also use classes from the Java runtime class libraries (such as java.lang.String) and may use third-party libraries. These classes need to be stored in memory for as long as they are being used. How classes are stored varies by implementation.
  >
  > Java-приложения состоят из классов, которые определяют структуру и поведение объектов. Классы могут предоставляться как JRE (например `java.lang.String`) так и сторонними библиотеками. Эти классы нужно хранить в памяти все время, пока они используются. Способ хранения в классов в памяти, зависит от реализации JVM.

И это не еще затрагивая **потоки**.  Главное, что нужно понять: параметр `-Xmx` не контролирует всю выделяемую для JVM память, он влияет только на доступную внутри JVM динамическую память (Java Heap), но далеко не все хранится в ней.